# How to exempt file or folder deletion in below code

Tags: batch-file

```
@echo off
set dump_path=C:\test
set dump_path1=C:\test\xyz
set dump_path2=C:\test\xyz.py
 

set max_days=0
 

forfiles -p %dump_path% -m *.* -d -%max_days% -c "cmd  /c del /q @path"
 
forfiles -p %dump_path% -d -%max_days% -c "cmd /c IF @isdir == TRUE rd /S /Q @path"
```

How to exempt dump_path1 and dump_path2 from in the above code. it is a periodic file and folder deletion script and i want to exempt few folder and files from deletion in the same. tried "IF not -p %dump_path1%" in the last 2 lines of the script.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "dump_path=C:\test\"
set "dump_path1=!dump_path!xyz"
set "dump_path2=!dump_path!xyz.py"
set "str=!dump_path1! !dump_path2!"
set "max_days=0"
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ('forfiles -p !dump_path! -m *.* -d -!max_days!^| findstr /v /i "!str!"') do (
    set "noext=%%~dpna"
    if "!noext!"=="%%a" (call rmdir %%a) else (call del %%a)
)
endlocal
```

If for some reason, the files/folders you want to skip contain <"spaces">, you must break up the findstr command and search for it/them literally, i.e.:

```
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ('forfiles -p !dump_path! -m *.* -d -!max_days!^| findstr /v /i /c:"!dump_path1!"^| findstr /v /i /c:"!dump_path2!"') do (
    set "noext=%%~dpna"
    if "!noext!"=="%%a" (call rmdir %%a) else (call del %%a)
)
```

Comment: thanks for the code but tried unfortunately batch file is not deleting any files in the specified folder

Comment: Please add the edit to your quesiton, from here it is unreadable..

Comment: @echo off

set "sourcedir=C:\test"
set "keepfile=xyz.py"
set "keepdir=xyz"

FOR /d %%a IN ("%sourcedir%\*") DO IF /i NOT "%%~nxa"=="%keepdir%" RD /S /Q "%%a"

FOR %%a IN ("%sourcedir%\* -d -0") DO IF /i NOT "%%~nxa"=="%keepfile%" del /q "%%a"

Comment: can u please add  -d -<numberofdays>   to the above code i tried adding but not working